# Python-friendly machine configuration management systems

Tags: python, puppet, chef

Are there machine configuration management systems akin to:

- Puppet
- Chef

which are natively, or at least intimately, Python-friendly?

Any recommendations with supporting evidence and/or backing reasoning as to why?

(The two systems above have a penchant for Ruby.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software

Comment: @goldilocks: thanks. do you also have a recommendation with an explanation as to why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't.  I just found that list when I looked up 'Puppet' ;)  Someone might come along here who's actually used them tho.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Ansible](http://ansibleworks.com/) is written in Python.  It's a slightly different take on configuration management that requires nothing on the target servers other than python (and python-simplejson for python < 2.6).

Answer (score 2):

Do not discount [Salt Stack](http://saltstack.com/) either.

It offers the ability to queue (built a top ZeroMQ) commands to your servers as well as configuration management.

Its python API is documented here: https://salt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/clients/index.html#python-api

Large companies such as Linkedin, HP Cloud Services, and Hulu use or used it.